# ListView is not updating after Delete

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nativescript, typescript1.8

While deleting an item from a ListView, the changes will not reflect in the ListView and it will not get updated in NativeScript. I am using Firebase as the backend, but the data is correctly updating in the database.

Anyone please help me. I'm providing my code files below. After splicing, I got the correct result but the list view will not bind with that data.

list.model.ts

```
function delete(id) {  
return firebase.remove("/Groceries/" + id + "");
};
```

list.ts

```
var items = [];
var itemsObject = new observableModule.fromObject({
groceryList: items
});

export function deleteValues(args) {
var item = args.view.bindingContext;
var page = <pages.Page>args.object;

deleteItems(item.key)
    .then(
    () => {
        items.splice(items.indexOf(item), 1);
        page.bindingContext = itemsObject;
    }
    ).catch(
    () => {
        alert("error");
    }
    )
    };
```

list.xml

```
<Page loaded="loaded">
<GridLayout rows="auto, *" columns="2*, *">
<TextField id="grocery" text="{{ grocery }}" hint="Enter a grocery   
item" row="0" col="0" />
    <Button text="Add" tap="addGrocery" row="0" col="1" />
    <ListView id="groceryList" items="{{ groceryList }}" row="1" 
       colSpan="2">
        <ListView.itemTemplate>
        <GridLayout columns="*, auto">
            <Label text="{{ name }}" horizontalAlignment="left" 
             verticalAlignment="center"/>
            <Image src="~/images/delete.png"  col="1" 
             tap="deleteValues" />
            </GridLayout>
        </ListView.itemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</GridLayout>
```

Comment: To force ListView update you could use `refresh` method. - https://docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/classes/_ui_list_view_.listview.html#refresh

Answer (score 1):

You still can define the itemList for ListView as an ObservableArray and use the the built-in `splice` [function](http://docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/classes/_data_observable_array_.observablearray.html#slice) to remove the target item:

So in your code:

```
var items = new Observable.ObservableArray<any>();
items.splice(index, 1);
```

Basically, it's the same as what you have done but it should updates if you are using ObservableArray instead of normal array

Comment: this works. but only first item get deleted. while deleting second item list will not get updating.